# Align item in linearlayout from right

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `linearlayout` contains two item. when i change the order of items the first item do not shown .this is my code when textview is in the right:

```
    <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
          >
               <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.AwesomeTextView
                   android:id="@+id/fontAwesomeText3"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                   android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                   android:paddingRight="8dp"
                   android:textColor="@color/icon_color3"
                   app:bootstrapBrand="success"
                   android:textSize="@dimen/big_icon_size"
                   app:fontAwesomeIcon="fa_reorder"
                   android:gravity="left" />

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/text_summery"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:ellipsize="end"
                   android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                   android:maxLines="4"
                   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                   android:textColor="#5A5A61"
                   android:textSize="13sp" />
           </LinearLayout>
```

this is layout when`textview` is in the left :

```
     <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
          >

               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/text_summery"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:ellipsize="end"
                   android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                   android:maxLines="4"
                   android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                   android:textColor="#5A5A61"
                   android:textSize="13sp" />
               <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.AwesomeTextView
                   android:id="@+id/fontAwesomeText3"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                   android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                   android:paddingRight="8dp"
                   android:textColor="@color/icon_color3"
                   app:bootstrapBrand="success"
                   android:textSize="@dimen/big_icon_size"
                   app:fontAwesomeIcon="fa_reorder"
                   android:gravity="left" />

           </LinearLayout>
```

but when `textview` is in the left , the font icon do not shown .why?

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent"  and it covers all screen width and second textview is not visible. replace match_parent to wrap_content

Comment: @USKMobility i did it,nothing changed

Comment: @serenei it's problem with only android:layout_width="match_parent" in your `TextView` change it to android:layout_width="wrap_content" i tried your xml in my project its work

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope this will help your

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_summery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
       <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.AwesomeTextView
       ..../>   
</LinearLayout>
```